# Where is Go To Special in Excel 2011 for Mac?

Tags: excel-2011

Does anyone know where the `Go To Special...` in Excel 2011 for Mac? In Windows, you can use `Ctrl+G`, but I cannot find it in the Mac version :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can open the Goto dialog box from the `Edit` menu or by pressing `F5`. From there, click the `Special` button or type Command-S.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions, <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> does bring up the `Go To…` dialog.

Confirming on Excel for Mac version 15.27.